# What does $C,D \models \delta$ mean?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm reading the following notes: http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~yorgey/settheory/
and on page 21 the following is proven:

If $C,D \models \delta$, then $C \cong_P D$.  where $\delta$ is the defined to be a formula of first-order logic which expresses the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense linear order without endpoints. And $C \cong_P D$ means that $C$ and $D$ are partially isomorphic.

However, it seems to me that since $\mathbb{Q} \models \delta$ that $\mathbb{Q},S \models \delta$ for any $S$ (since that would just be superfluous information).  Therefore, by the lemma, we should get $\mathbb{Q} \cong_P S$ for any set $S$.  This seems terribly off, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 2):

It just means $C\vDash \delta$ and $D\vDash \delta$.  Note that here we are talking about models, not sets of sentences, so it wouldn't make sense to consider "$C,D$" as representing some sort of union or conjunction of $C$ and $D$.

Comment: But what does it mean that $\mathbb{Q} \models \delta$?  Or is that non-sense?  Or is there an equivocation of symbols?  The LHS of the lemma is about models and the RHS is about their underlying sets?  So $\mathbb{Q} \models \delta$ isn't about the set $\mathbb{Q}$, right? But rather the model, correct?  Because a collection of points (like $\mathbb{Q}$) doesn't really say / model anything, in and of itself.

Comment: The author is using $\mathbb{Q}$ as a shorthand for the structure $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$. This is a model of the theory of DLOs w/o endpoints.

Comment: Yes, it's extremely common to just write the underlying set of a structure instead of the entire tuple.